# Force IE10 Default quirks mode when in Compatiblity view

Tags: internet-explorer-10, quirks-mode

One of our clients uses compatibility view for our site. Our website pages are old and cannot render in Standards mode. In IE10 compatibility view, if there is no doctype declaration, it forces it to IE5 Quirks mode. 
Is there a way from html to force it to IE Default Quirks mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  Use an x-ua-compatible header to emulate IE10's behavior.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE10">
```

You can add this to each page's `<HEAD>` section or serve it [using the web server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj676913(v=vs.85).aspx).

(More of the underlying behavior change can be [found here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh869300(v=vs.85).aspx).)

Hope this helps...

-- Lance

Comment: Is there a way to force it to render in EmulateIE10 in IE 10 and edge otherwise? If I set <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE10;IE=edge"> then the mode changes to Standards mode in IE10 instead of remaining in quirk mode.

Comment: Off the top of my head, consider trying either a) "EmulateIE9" (which will lose you the IE10 extensions or b) reversing the two values you're currently using.  (I don't recall if the rule is "last match wins," "first match wins," or if it changed between versions, something I strongly suspected but never verified.)  The problem for your case is IE10's "interoperable HTML5 quirks mode."  (Option C, of course, is to look at the page and see why it needs IE5 quirks mode.  Maybe there's a better way?)

Comment: I tried reversing the two values, still rendered in standards mode. Setting Emulate IE9 also doesn't work - it looks like as long as edge is in there, it'll render in standards mode. I was looking into why the page needs quirk mode, one thing is all my legacy css(tons of it) have various properties with no px set. Eg: padding:2; This renders in IE10 standards mode with no padding at all if the css is used within a table. If I change it to padding:2px; then it renders fine in standards mode in IE10. In IE11 and quirks mode however padding:2; is not a problem at all. It is very frustrating.